# how to write this python code as a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I need to turn this lines into a list comprehension

```py
ag_averaged = []
for i in range(len(i_averaged)-1):
    max_av = max(a_g[ i_averaged [i]:i_averaged [i+1]])
    ag_averaged.append( max_av)
```

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: This isn't a homework completion service, @Marco. We're more than happy to help, but we want to see that you've made attempts to solve this.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score -1):

Leaving out that you do not deliver working, reproducible code, this is what should make the same job:

```
ag_averaged = [max(a_g[ i_averaged[i]:i_averaged[i+1] ]) for i in range(len(i_averaged)-1)]
```